# Cannot install show because of FQDN

Tags: linux, networking, apt-get

When i install show (sudo apt-get install nmh). It fails with the following error :

```
The hostname -f command returned: $1

Your system needs to have a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) in
order to install the var-qmail packages.
```

but if i do : `hostname -f`, it returns :

> ubuntu-sylario

Why does my install fails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is not an FQDN. You would need something like ubuntu-sylario.example.com, you can set by making /etc/hostname contain `ubuntu-sylario` and /etc/hosts to have (on the line containing either 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 if you use Debian/ubuntu and make sure it has FQDN followed by hostname, i.e: `127.0.0.1 ubuntu-sylario.example.com ubuntu-sylario`. On next reboot check with `hostname` and `hostname -f` which should report `ubuntu-sylario` and `ubuntu-sylario.example.com` respectively

Answer (score 1):

Do the following, one line at a time:

```
sudo apt-get purge qmail qmail-run tripwire mailutils
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that the installer is demanding something that isn't needed by qmail, or indeed by smtp. But, the alternative, if you don't want to buy or fake an fqdn (you could tell it you were foo.amazon.com if you wanted) is either to install from source (eg using life with qmail) or use something like qmail-rocks. The problem you'll then get is that when you distribution upgrade your system it's likely to break your qmail installation. So, pressurise the BOFH wannabe package maintainer to take out this silly requirement. And while they're at it, they could offer something useful in the kind of way exim installation does, such as asking if you want to use a smarthost (you probably do if you're installing on a machine without an fqdn, and you need to specify it in qmail's control file smtproutes).